# Get assembly path from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a `MethodInfo` from a method out of a class library. 
Is it possible to determine the path where the `assembly` is located with just that info?

```
void foo(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{ 
    // Get the path of the DLL here
   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the location the assembly was found, use `CodeBase` instead of `Location` i.e.

```
methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.Codebase
```

see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/assembly-codebase-vs-assembly-location.aspx) for a description of the difference. If your assembly is being shadow copied, you may find `CodeBase` more useful.

Comment: That exactly what's my environment does. Thank you that works!

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location
```

?

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it seems that my environment copies the assemble do anaother directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location`?